# Abrir arquivo texto e tratar por linha

Tags: golang

Estou começando os primeiros passo em [go](/questions/tagged/go) e estou precisando primeiramente pegar um arquivo texto abrir ele e filtrar por linha onde cada linha está separado por `|` e vou fazer um `if` pra mostrar determinada linha

Exemplo:

Conteúdo do arquivo texto:

```
|C100|1|0||55|05|1|000002397||||||||||||||||||||||
|C100|1|0||55|05|1|000002399||||||||||||||||||||||
|C100|1|0||55|05|1|000002425||||||||||||||||||||||
|C100|1|0||55|05|1|000002371||||||||||||||||||||||
|C400|2D|ECF|asdasda2330|002|
|C405|02012012|3|1036|116526|6001060,09|5693,36|
|C420|DT|151,78|||
|C420|01T1700|429,50|01||
|C420|F1|5112,08|||
|C460|2D|00|116397|02012012|25,00|0,16|0,75|||
|C470|0000008556|2,000|0|RL|25,00|060|5403|0|0,16|0,75|
|C460|2D|00|116398|02012012|27,67|0,19|0,83|||
|C470|0000015177|1,000|0|RL|5,60|060|5403|0|0,04|0,17|
|C470|0000022346|1,000|0|RL|5,60|060|5403|0|0,04|0,17|
|C470|0000025882|1,000|0|PC|6,09|060|5403|0|0,04|0,18|
|C470|0000025885|2,000|0|PC|10,38|060|5403|0|0,07|0,31|
|C460|2D|00|116399|02012012|19,90|0,13|0,60|||
|C470|0000000247|3,000|0|RLO|10,20|060|5403|0|0,07|0,31|
|C470|0000020634|1,000|0|PC|9,70|060|5403|0|0,06|0,29|
|C460|2D|00|116400|02012012|10,52|0,07|0,32|||
|C470|0000004762|1,000|0|CAT|1,12|060|5403|0|0,01|0,03|
|C470|0000008873|1,000|0|PC|1,94|060|5403|0|0,01|0,06|
|C470|0000016902|1,000|0|PC|3,68|060|5403|0|0,02|0,11|
|C470|0000023287|1,000|0|PC|1,26|060|5403|0|0,01|0,04|
|C470|0000023303|1,000|0|PC|1,26|060|5403|0|0,01|0,04|
|C470|0000023308|1,000|0|PC|1,26|060|5403|0|0,01|0,04|
|C460|2D|00|116401|02012012|5,00|0,04|0,16|||
|C470|0000009772|1,000|0|UN|1,25|000|5102|17,00|0,01|0,04|
|C470|0000009789|1,000|0|UN|1,25|000|5102|17,00|0,01|0,04|
|C470|0000009826|1,000|0|UN|1,25|000|5102|17,00|0,01|0,04|
|C470|0000009842|1,000|0|UN|1,25|000|5102|17,00|0,01|0,04|
```

Preciso primeiro abrir o arquivo e armazenar todo conteúdo dele e depois fazer tipo um explode de cada linha colocando em um *array*
feito isso vou fazer um `if linha[1] == "C460"` e mostra o conteúdo todo dessa linha

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
)


func main() {
    conteudo,_ := ioutil.ReadFile("sped.txt")
    linhas := strings.Split(string(conteudo),"|")
    for _,v := range (linhas){
        if v == "C100"{
            fmt.Println(v) // preciso mostra a linha toda do registro C100
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(linhas[1])

}
```

Comment: Se você quer pegar a linha, o seu `strings.Split` deve considerar o separador `\n` e não `|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Não utilize split, ele remove o carácter passado no segundo parametro e retorna uma string do resultado do conteúdo.
2. Quando você fez um for você comparou se todo o arquivo é igual a C100, mas você precisa comparar coluna por coluna de cada linha.

Fiz com expressão regular, veja se é isso, neste caso é só trocar o nome pelo conteúdo exemplo: C100,C470

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    // abrindo arquivo sped.txt
    conteudo, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("sped.txt")

    nome := "C100" // nome que irá procurar...

    // expressão regular que verifica se o nome existe, se existe ele pega todo conteúdo
    r, err := regexp.Compile("(?P<name>" + nome + ").+")

    // verifica se houve algum erro ao pegar o conteudo
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Ocorreu um erro: %v", err)
    }

    // cria um slice de string para cada linha de string encontrada
    x := strings.Fields(string(conteudo))

    // percorre todo o slice de string
    for _, a := range x {
        fmt.Println(r.FindString(string(a))) // retorna apenas as linhas pelo nome escolhido
    }
}
```

Link para o código completo, https://play.golang.org/p/U_dniiFOeJ porém não vai funcionar porque dentro do servidor não tem o arquivo sped.txt, então você copia e executa localmente.